# I want my Program to fully control the I/O for cmd line program running in the console Window(any language)

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to call an old 32bit Application from within my program, which happens to be a C# Program(easy enough). But I want my program to Control this Console application, to send key strokes directly to the running console application.

How can I do this ideally in C# or any other language? I want to fully control the I/O for cmd line program running.

Comment: ***How can I do this ideally in C# or any other language?*** In Qt I would use QProcess it has the ability to control the input and output of the console applicaton. With that said, I am sure you can do this in c# and not have to resort to a different framework and language.

Comment: Using pipes for standard I/O is intended for non-interactive programs. Most programs fully buffer I/O to pipe and disk files, which interferes with interactive use. Windows 10 has ConPTY pseudoconsole support. The child process sees a normal console session, and the parent process is attached to the console session over a pair of pipes instead of to the child's standard I/O. The parent thus has full control over console input and full control to render console output to any window.

Comment: Can Anyone share code showing how to call and inject key strokes into a command window. e.g Call notepad and type "XYZ" in the notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUTO IT API was the Answer here